# $state.go not working the way I expect in angular.js ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a master/detail form with ui-router subviews.

**Technique 1** (Working)

I use **ui-sref** to activate the edit panel when a user clicks on an edit button, this works fine.

When I click on the edit button for the first time or for subsequent times my panel is activated and all is good.

```
<a ui-sref=".edit({id: row.entity[\'id\']})"  class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Edit</a>
```

**Technique 2 (Fails)**

I decided to try doing the same in the controller using essentially the same format for the state transition.

This only works the first time the user clicks panel, i.e. before a panel has ever been activated. Subsequent clicks fail with this error.

```
// Only Works for the 1st Click
$state.go('.edit', { id: id });
```

**Technique 3** (Works)

I was able to get it working by going this way, now it works for 1st click and subsequent clicks.

```
// All ways works
$state.go('skill.edit', { id: id });
```

**Why does Technique 2 Fails?**

I've obviously switched into some sort of lower level state with technique 2, but I'm not sure how I can use that technique correctly?

Below are the screen shots from Technique 2 from before 1st click, to after 1st click to after 2nd click.

[image: Screenshots of the Issue]

[image: Error I am seeing]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the first works because all those `ui-sref` values are calculated before the state changes, ie they're all relative from the parent state (`skill`).

When you try and do it in the controller, once the state has already changed to `skill.edit` you're telling it to go to the relative `.edit` state which resolves to `skill.edit.edit`

Comment: That's what I thought might be happening, but when I have looked at examples around using state.go(), they don't tend to make this distinction, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a clear tutorial that explains how to use state.go in this particular scenario